# Anonymous function inheriting variable from parent scope which contains variable

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I am trying to declare anonymous functions in a loop, but one of the variables contains the variable name.
This is the code I am using:

```
$GREEN = "MY GREEN";
$RED = "MY RED";
$BLUE = "MY BLUE";
$colors = array( 'red', 'green', 'blue');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($colors); $i++)  {
    $color = strtoupper($colors[$i]);
     ${$colors[$i]} = function ($text) use ($color) {
          echo $text . " is " . $color . "\n";
      };
}
$green("HELLO");
$red("HELLO");
$blue("HELLO");
```

The result shows:

```
HELLO is GREEN
HELLO is RED
HELLO is BLUE
```

But I would like it to show:

```
HELLO is MY GREEN
HELLO is MY RED
HELLO is MY BLUE
```

I cannot manage to get it done in PHP.  Obviously `use ($color)` is not what I need, but `use (${$color})` also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not a fan of variable variables and prefer arrays, you can solve this before passing the colour to the function...

```
$color = ${strtoupper($colors[$i])};
```

Comment: Thank Nigel. Exactly what I needed. I trying several ways but now I see how simple it was. BTW I cannot accept the answer, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the variables at the top you'll need to include them as well.

This is your code with minimal changes. I collected the variables to a single array for easier use and also to avoid a large `use` list.

```
$my_colors = [
  'GREEN' => "MY GREEN",
  'RED'=> "MY RED",
  'BLUE' => "MY BLUE"
];
$colors = array( 'red', 'green', 'blue');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($colors); $i++)  {
    $color = strtoupper($colors[$i]);
     ${$colors[$i]} = function ($text) use ($color, $my_colors) {
          echo $text . " is " . $my_colors[$color] . "\n";
      };
}
$green("HELLO");
$red("HELLO");
$blue("HELLO");
```

Comment: Thank you Gil. This is a nice approach that I've seen also in other answers, but the colors is just an example. I need to generate many functions and passing along an array seems much overhead for just a simple task.